# Object property is undefined when i try to show it or console.log - React & Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a little new to react and i can't understand why my object property is undefined but when i console.log my object is appearing okay see this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of console.log]

This is my custom hook **useForm**:

```
const useForm = (callback, validateRegister) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPass: '',
  });
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validateRegister(values)); // validateReister is another function that returns and object with these properties.
    setIsSubmitting(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
      callback();
    }
  }, [errors]);

  return {
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    errors,
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

**Component:**

```
  const { handleChange, handleSubmit, values, errors } = useForm(
    submit,
    validateRegister
  );
```

**Problem:**

```
{errors.nameError}
```

Is not showing up, is not appearing on console.log either. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `validateRegister(values)` returns a `Promise`. Try changing your implementation to the below :-

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    validateRegister(values).then(data => setErrors(data)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    setIsSubmitting(true);
  };
```

Comment: ohh god, I forgot to remove the "async" keyword in the validateRegister function, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `setErrors(validateRegister(values));` with

```
validateRegister(values).then(data => setErrors(data)).catch(e => console.log(e));
```